# Is the Azure Active Directory Access Token valid for ReAuthentication with a Custom WCF Policy?

Tags: azure, wcf, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I am retrieving an Azure AD access token using MSAL.js at the client and passing it as Authorization header to web api hosted in WCF API Management. But I get an error along with all the proper response as well my username and email

> Cannot validate access token. IDX10501: Signature validation failed.
> Key tried: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey

The API is a WCF service configured with a custom policy binding for OAuth with the metadataEndpoint or even the v2 version [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenantid%7D/.well-known/openid-configuration)  .

I guess the Azure AD Access token that I have is not meant for validating authentication again.
My guess I might be either missing permissions on the App registration but I couldn't find an API permission for exact authentication/authorization.
I believe with new Azure AD , we cannot authenticate the earlier manner by just passing a token and need to use MSAL standard libraries.
Could someone shed some more light on this.

Answer (score 0):

I used an ID Token and then it worked. You get 2 tokens when authenticated so the ID token seems to work.